# Would it hurt anything to leave a canister stove attached overnight?

Tags: cooking, canister-stoves

If I cook a hot dinner on a canister stove and plan on cooking a hot breakfast in the morning, **can I leave the stove on the canister overnight** or would it be **better to take it off** and reattach in the morning?

Answer (score 7):

No, go ahead and leave it on, you'll likely save fuel that way, be it a very small amount, but you do lose some fuel each time you take the element off of the canister. You don't need to take it off if you're not packing it away.

Answer (score 5):

My experience is with portable grills and cooktops.  They're a bit different, but close enough that I think this may be informative.

The valves on cheaper ($50-200) camping grills aren't the best.  I've owned two that still put out some gas when they're "off".  If you take the whole valve out of the grill and hold your hand over the pinhole, you can feel a small breeze.

I usually leave the canister attached if the grill is staying outdoors, but I unscrew the canister if the grill is going in my basement.

After unscrewing the canister, put your hand over the valve and feel for a breeze.  I've had canisters that their internal valve doesn't close after unscrewing.  Just pay attention and screw it back onto the grill and rely on the grill's valve.

Answer (score 5):

Note that with some canister stoves, once the canister is fitted it has to stay on until empty. These work by the stove piercing the canister instead of the canister having a valve and thread. That means they don't seal if you try to take them off, and vent all the gas rapidly.

The continued existence of this old design suggests that if on another type removal was strictly required, it would be clearly labelled, and it's not.

Comment: I'm surprised no one made this point when the question was asked - or maybe someone did (me?) but it in a now-deleted comment.

Comment: Can confirm no deleted comments on this question or answers :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I can only assume that I missed it at the time, then

Comment: Do any of these piercing cartridges still exist on the open market? I used the Bluet cartridges of this type in the 1980s, but I haven't seen anything like it in decades.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant my blowtorch uses them. That's a few years old now but even if you can't buy the burner any more, they're still around and it's not long since I bought gas for it

Comment: You can still get Campingaz 206 burners and lanterns

Answer (score 0):

Provided you don't leave it in an open place. I don't think animals would be able to turn a knob. But they could jump on it an loosen the screw of the attachment.